# Invert a large sized matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse

I have a big matrix of size 200000 x 200000. I need to compute its inverse. But it gives out of memory error. Is there any algorithm to approximate and compute the inverse of a large sized matrix.

Comment: For what do yo need to invert the matrix?, is for solve a linear system?

Comment: @TheStudent No, it is not a linear system. It is actually a hessian matrix in neural network. I need to invert it to compute the weight salience.

Comment: Without a **lot** more context this question is impossible to answer except for the trivial "Get more memory!".

Comment: If the matrix is sparse there are ways to do it. But otherwise it should be impossible to even store the original matrix in the first place. You have $4\times 10^{10}$ entries which is a ton.

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo Here the matrix is not sparse. Is there an algorithm to approximate the inverse when matrix is large?

Comment: but how are you going to fit the matrix in the first place? are you going to store it in a hard drive?

Comment: you can make all of the calculations in the hard drive but it would be slooww. Like maybe a couple of years

Comment: If you take a byte per entry (so, you are not even allowing more or less arbitrary integers) your matrix occupies 37GB. What kind of system do you use that has that kind of RAM?